# MatLab Windows Media Player ActiveX No Video Shown

Tags: matlab, activex

I created a GUI with a push button and an ActiveX Windows Media Player. When the button is clicked, the video is playing the audio only, no video is being displayed at the Windows Media Player. Why is that so?

```
function playButton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to playButton (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
handles.activex1.URL = 'Test.mp4';
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try "handles.activex1.controls.play". It is working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

try this code    :

```
m=figure
actx = actxcontrol('WMPlayer.ocx.7',[40,20,285,350],m); % Create Controller
actx.URL=[VideoPath VideoName]; % Create Media object
actx.controls.play
```